# ssh delay seriously

Tags: ssh

I have my own DNS name. Thus, I could connect my raspberry pi through ssh using command pi@example.com. It works well at beginning days I bought it. But in these days it's often no-responsive. And some times, it even hard to login.

I have try to find solution for such situation:

1. enlarge the swap space.
2. setting UseDNS to no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
3. use `ssh -4 -v`

But all of them did work out.

I use free -h to see if the memory is not enough:

```
$ free -h
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          925M       878M        47M        11M        22M       761M
-/+ buffers/cache:        94M       831M
Swap:         2.0G         0B       2.0G
```

It seems that I still have enough memory space.

About my network speed, I test ssh to connect AWS instance, and it works well. I **ping** my domain:

```
icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.13 ms
icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.53 ms
icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=5.01 ms
icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=2.37 ms
```

So, any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that the Pi isn't overheating. Set up domain name again and if possible try re-installing the OS.